# Delimiter size \big not working with fourier, mathtools packages and 11pt option

Tags: delimiters, mathtools, fourier

I have a document using the fourier font package and mathtools. In mathmode the \big delimiters are the same size as normal sized.

After some debugging I noticed that if I remove the `11pt` document option, then this delimiter size does work correctly. This seems to be a bug to me, but my TeX knowledge is too limited to trace it further. Any pointers as to whether this is a bug (and in which package) would be appreciated.

A MWE below. If I remove the `11pt` option the norm delimiters are scaled correctly to increasing sizes. Other delimiters such as parentheses scale correctly under both circumstances.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \|\,\big\|\,\Big\|
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`amsmath` changes the way LaTeX builds `\big` delimiters based on the dimensions of a parenthesis. Unfortunately the parenthesis is not as high as `amsmath` expects. I found a correction that seems to work:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}

\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
  \ht\Mathstrutbox@1.2\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@1.2\dp\z@
}
\makeatother
```

(notice that `mathtools` is not involved in this, but it's the called `amsmath` package the important one.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}

\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
  \ht\Mathstrutbox@1.2\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@1.2\dp\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\|\,\big\|\,\Big\|\,\bigg\|\,\Bigg\|
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, indeed this also works. Are there any possible side effects I should be aware of, and is this solution better than what I found?

Comment: It *may* not work with other growing delimiters; I tried with `(`, `[` and `\lbrace`, the results seem good.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found at least [a way to solve it](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1792); I added

```
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{11.3}{7.7}{5.5}
```

to my preamble. I'd be glad if anyone could explain why this is necessary, or if there is a better solution.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, as it changes the size of all math fonts. An "a" in math mode will be 3% higher than an "a" in text mode. Moreover, it won't distinguish between `\Big` and `\bigg`, for instance.