# Cambria Math \bigg command doesn't work as expected

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, delimiters, mathtools

I get wrong sizes when I use `\bigg` and family with Cambria. Here is an example (I loaded `mathtools` before `unicode-math` and then my actual problem showed up). We can see that the size `\bigg` exists because it works well without `mathtools`, and also if I use `\left`/`\right` construction:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[
    \Biggl( \biggl( \Bigl( \bigl( ( a ) \bigr) \Bigr) \biggr) \Biggr)
\]
\[
    \Biggl( \left( \Bigl( \bigl( ( a ) \bigr) \Bigr)^2 \right) \Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try loading `amsmath` before `unicode-math`?

Comment: Thanks @egreg, now that's the real problem in my document ;) I tried to make a minimal example, but it didn't work even if `mathtools` wasn't loaded so I posted it anyways.

Comment: This seems related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61023/delimiter-size-big-not-working-with-fourier-mathtools-packages-and-11pt-option

Comment: @egreg Far above my limits. I just pasted it AFTER `unicode-math` and uploaded the result to the question. As you said: related, but I don't know.

Comment: The magnification factor (1.2 in the version for the linked question, 1 as default) should be fine tuned for the font used. Acting on `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` might also help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For explanation run `texdoc mathmode` and read  "8.3 Problems  with  parentheses"

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\delimitershortfall=-1pt%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\[
    \Biggl( \biggl( \Bigl( \bigl( ( a ) \bigr) \Bigr) \biggr) \Biggr)
\]
\[
    \Biggl( \left( \Bigl( \bigl( ( a ) \bigr) \Bigr)^2 \right) \Biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show also the effect on matrices and the like? I would, but I don't have Cambria Math.

Comment: Still not sure. With this, it's like TeX is not using the original `\bigg` and `\Big` glyphs, but another ones (may be a re-scaled ones?). By the way, how many sizes/glyphs of *delimiters* exist? I always thought there were four (`big`, `Big`, etc.) and then started the expandable. But with this example it's obvious you can get bigger sizes without relying in the expandables.

Comment: @Manuel: The number of sizes available is font dependent, and Cambria has many sizes than most of other math fonts. Also `\big` and co macros are tuned for Computer Modern fonts, so they might not work for all other fonts (and there nothing special about these macros, they just define an empty box of certain height to force the delimiter to grow, and that why they might not work the same for all fonts).

Comment: @KhaledHosny Great explanation. So this “partially” solves the problem, but then what I really want is to obtain all the possible sizes. I accept this answer and will open a new question.