# kpfonts vs. fence scaling

Tags: delimiters, kpfonts

Consider this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
 (\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg(
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

Compare it to the same code without, `kpfonts`

[image]

You will notice that the shift from `(` to `\big(` is much less dramatic.

Does anyone know if this can be changed somehow?

The jump makes things like this look ugly:

```
\[ \big\{ \{x\} : x \in X \big\}  \]
```

[image]

---

This workaround provided by Steven below, seems useful

```
\newlength\axisht
\setlength{\axisht}{\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox}
\def\scalemathaxis#1#2{\raisebox{\dimexpr\axisht-#1\axisht}{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}
\newcommand\mbigl[1]{\mathopen{\scalemathaxis{0.8}{\big#1}}}
\newcommand\mbigr[1]{\mathclose{\scalemathaxis{0.8}{\big#1}}}
\[ (\mbigl(\big( \]
```

will then give a more reasonable middle step.

[image]

---

UPDATE June 18. The developer acknowledges the problem but have no time to fix it. His best solution would be to grap the fences from a different font. Which would require remapping every single fence being used, via `\DeclareMathDelimiter` for suitable values, which also require knowledge about which spots in the font the fences are located.

Comment: I guess playing with `\delimitershortfall` and family might solve it. But I don't know enough. May be [this approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146639/21930) pleases you.

Comment: By the way, I think that the answer is a design “decision”. There are only 4 levels before the “stretching version”, i.e., your example: `(`, `\bigl(`, `\Bigl(` and `\biggl(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `.tfm` file of `jkpex` (the font used for large symbols) converted into PL format, we find the following character series:

```
(CHARACTER O 0
   (CHARWD R 0.381)
   (CHARHT R 0.058499)
   (CHARDP R 0.943999)
   (NEXTLARGER O 20)
   )

(CHARACTER O 20
   (CHARWD R 0.395)
   (CHARHT R 0.058499)
   (CHARDP R 1.472)
   (NEXTLARGER O 22)
   )

(CHARACTER O 22
   (CHARWD R 0.408)
   (CHARHT R 0.058499)
   (CHARDP R 1.982)
   (NEXTLARGER O 40)
   )

(CHARACTER O 40
   (CHARWD R 0.422)
   (CHARHT R 0.058499)
   (CHARDP R 2.4885)
   (NEXTLARGER C 0)
   )

(CHARACTER C 0
   (CHARWD R 0.441)
   (CHARHT R 0.0259)
   (CHARDP R 0.8335)
   (VARCHAR
      (TOP C 0)
      (BOT O 100)
      (REP C B)
      )
   )
```

Here the story ends: we have reached the stage where the parenthesis is built up from pieces.

The `\delcode` of the parenthesis is `"28300`, which means that when an enlarged open parenthesis is needed for `\left`, TeX will look in slot `"00` of family `"3`. Note that `\big` and friends do use `\left` and `\right` internally. TeX will try and find the size that best fits, starting from slot `"00` and following the character series defined with `NEXTLARGER`.

If I add `\showlists` in your math display, I find that `\big(` is

```
\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 ^^P
```

Here's the relevant diagnostic:

```
\mathopen
.\fam0 (
\mathord
.\hbox(10.1525+5.1525)x3.95
..\mathon
..\hbox(10.1525+5.1525)x3.95
...\hbox(0.58499+14.72)x3.95, shifted -9.5675
....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 ^^P
...\vbox(8.46397+3.46396)x0.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted -2.5
..\mathoff
```

In the format TeX uses for these diagnostic messages, `^^P` means character octal 20. For `\Big(` we get

```
\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 ^^R
```

(octal 22), for `\bigg(` we get

```
\OMX/jkp/m/n/10
```

(octal 40, nothing is seen because it's the space), for `\Bigg(` we get

```
...\vbox(0.25899+27.43994)x4.40999, shifted -16.09047
....\hbox(0.25899+8.33499)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 0
....\hbox(-0.19+2.93)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 B
....\hbox(-0.19+2.93)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 B
....\hbox(-0.19+2.93)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 B
....\hbox(-0.19+2.93)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 B
....\hbox(-0.19+8.33499)x4.40999
.....\OMX/jkp/m/n/10 @
```

(I'm showing the whole box, because this demonstrates a built up parenthesis is used).

What happens? The smallest slot is missed. The character is too small to be picked up. It's clearly a bug in the font; I have tried with various combinations of `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor`, but without success.

Here's something that should clarify the matter. The `amsmath` package redefines the macros for `\big` and so on; it uses a hook for resetting the math strut which the `bBigg` variants are built upon. If I redefine the macro using a smaller dimension than resulting from the usual computations, the right series is chosen:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
  \ht\Mathstrutbox@0.94\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@0.94\dp\z@
}
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{0.99}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
 (\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg(%\showlists
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see well that the first two parentheses are *different*: the first is from the normal font, the second one is what's picked up in slot `"00` of `jkpex`. You can clearly see that its size is *almost exactly* the same as the normal parenthesis. This is why it's not picked up unless the devious trick of redefinining `\big` is performed; but even if it's chosen, it's useless, because it isn't really bigger than the normal parenthesis.

So the main problem is that the normal parenthesis is too big; not really a problem, because the setting of the math strut can be fixed as shown. But the `\big` variant should be larger.

Comment: So it might be better to send a bug report to the maintainers. But what should they do about it?

Comment: @daleif Fix the size of the character in slot `"00`, but also the other ones, so that there's no jump. I'll try some other workaround.

Comment: I'll send the maintainer an email, and refer to your break down of the issue.

Comment: @daleif I think to have come to a conclusion. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

TOTALLY REVISED ANSWER:

After my initial confusion subsided over whether the OP was unhappy with the glyph shape (no) or the glyph size (yes), and in offline discussions with him, I realized the crux was the *size* of the `\big` paren, and *we* realized the problem preventing an easy fix was that simple scaling does not preserve the math axis.

So, in this solution, I created macro `\scalemathaxis{number}{math expression}` to scale the glyph while preserving the math axis.  While obviously typing `\scalemathaxis{0.85}{\big(}` every time you wanted a slightly smaller `\big(` could get tedious, it can be placed in a macro directly, if desired.

The key here is in realizing that the math axis is located at a height of `.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox` above the baseline.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newlength\axisht
\setlength{\axisht}{\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox}
\def\scalemathaxis#1#2{\raisebox{\dimexpr\axisht-#1\axisht}{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}
\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt
\[
(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg( \quad (^2\big(^2\Big(^2\bigg(^2\Bigg(^2
\]
\[
(\scalemathaxis{0.85}{\big(}\Big(\bigg(\Bigg( \quad
(^2\scalemathaxis{0.85}{\big(}^2\Big(^2\bigg(^2\Bigg(^2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a hackish solution, and not something I'd consider recommending. IMO this is a real problem with the `kpfonts` package, and I'd rather know if this is a design decision, or a package defect.

Comment: @daleif  Please see my total revision, that allows scaling while preserving the math axis.

Comment: Now, that was much more useful. I've updated my edit with a usable step between `(` and `\big(`