# Unable to produce big math slash with kpfonts-otf

Tags: unicode-math, kpfonts

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \left. \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The slash in the middle should be a bigger one. For example, if one uses `kpfonts` instead of `kpfonts-otf`, the result would be:

[image]

Is there some way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183477/kpfonts-vs-fence-scaling helps you? This also will helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436284/how-to-adjust-parenthesis-thickness-without-changing-the-font/436290#436290

Comment: Apparently the developers forgot to add the larger variants…

Comment: I would ordinarily suggest `\usepackage[slash-delimiter=...]{unicode-math}`, but neither `\slash`, `\fracslash` nor `\divslash` works with this font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

With version 0.43 of `kpfonts-otf`, released 2022-07-05`, the issue has been fixed.

#### Original answer

It seems that the developers forgot to add the larger variants.

Workaround follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\DeclareSymbolFont{legacylargesymbols}{OMX}{jkp}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{/}{\mathord}{operators}{"2F}{legacylargesymbols}{"0E}

\begin{document}

$/\big/\Big/\bigg/$

\[
    \left. \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you should use `\Bigg/` instead of `\left. \middle/ \right.`

```
\[
  \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \Bigg/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y}
\]
```

Even better, no `\limits` and a thin space:

```
\[
  \int_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \,\Bigg/ \int_c^d \frac{x}{y}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I shall adopt this workaround until the final fix arrive.

Comment: The glyphs for larger variants *are* there, but I forgot to link them to the base characters. Same for \backslash. FIxed in version 0.43 which is on the way to CTAN. Thanks for pointing this out.