# Vertical bar delimiter too big with mathdesign's fonts

Tags: symbols, delimiters, mathdesign

With the utopia or charter fonts from `mathdesign`, the size of the vertical bar delimiter does not match the surrounding delimiters, except for the smallest size. I do not know about garamond (not installed on my system).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign} % same problem with [charter]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    [|] \quad
    \big[ \big| \big] \quad 
    \Big[ \Big| \Big] \quad
    \bigg[ \bigg| \bigg] \quad
    \left[ \vphantom{\sum_0^0} \middle| \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a bug or a design choice? Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's a design choice or not, but, concerning `utopia`, the `fourier` package, also based on this font, doesn't have this drawback: the difference is ca 0.3pt. I  advise to load also `erewhon`, a utopia clone, which adds real smallcaps (in roman, italic, bold and bold italic), inferior and superior figures and a few other treats.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ 
[|] \quad
\bigl[ \bigm| \bigr] \quad
\Bigl[ \Bigm| \Bigr] \quad
\biggl[ \biggm| \biggr] \quad
\Biggl[ \Biggm| \Biggr] \quad
\left[ \dfrac{\sqrt{\sum_0^{n}}}{n^2} \middle| \right]
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I'll use the `fourier` package for later use of utopia (although it seems that it has its [own problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61023/70966)).